# Change UploadCollection upload button text

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm using the [`UploadCollection`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollection). There is a standard plus button in the top right corner in which the user can upload a new file. I want to add a text "Add new item" to this button.

The standard API documentation doesn't mention anything about this button. Fiori guidelines states that it is not recommended but my user still wants to show it.

Is there any way to make this possible?

The control is used like this:

```xml
<UploadCollection id = "uploadCollection"
                  multiple = "true"
                  class = "sapUiNoMargin"
                  noDataText = "{i18n>noDataText}"
                  noDataDescription = "{i18n>noDataDescription}"
                  items = "{
                    path: 'app>/attachments',
                    templateShareable: false
                  }"
                  change = "onChangeUploadCollection"
                  beforeUploadStarts = "onBeforeUploadStarts"
                  fileDeleted = "onPressFileDelete"
                  uploadUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/xxx"
                  fileType = "{app>/filetypes}"
                  uploadComplete = "onUploadComplete"
                  typeMissmatch = "onTypeMissmatch">    
</UploadCollection>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to manipulate the button via the corresponding [`FileUploader`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader). As it is not intended to do that, [`UploadCollection`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.UploadCollection) does not provide a public method to access the `FileUploader` instance. However you can use the method `_getFilerUploader`, which is marked as private, to achieve this.

To display the upload button's text just add the following line to your controllers `onInit` method:

```js
this.byId('uploadCollection')._getFileUploader().setIconOnly(false)
```

To manipulate the button text you can use method `setButtonText`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. This was the answer I was looking for. I'm fairly new to JS so I haven't though about the private functions. 

I've fixed it on the prototype because the UploadCollection is added in runtime.
UploadCollection.prototype.onAfterRendering = function () {
                    this._getFileUploader().setIconOnly(false);
                    this._getFileUploader().setIconFirst(true);
                    this._getFileUploader().setButtonText('New');
                }

Comment: You're welcome. Private is a bit misleading here. The function itself is public (as JavaScript comes w/o member visibility by default), but is marked as privated. Thus it can change.